# Angular extend Array with dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to create an Angular module. In this module I want to extend Array with a property 'http' of Angular's type 'HttpClient'.

To extend Array I created a typings.d.ts file as follows:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

interface Array<T> {
  http: HttpClient;
}
```

Then I have an array.ts file with the following (just for example; undefined to be replaced with instance of HttpClient):

```
Array.prototype.http = undefined;
```

On this line I get following error:

> Property 'http' does not exist on type 'any[]'

However when I remove the import statement from my typings.d.ts file the original error disapears but I get following error on the typings.d.ts file

> Cannot find name 'HttpClient'

I'm probably missing something on how modules work in Typescript
I'm using TS vs 2.3.4

Comment: you cannot assign the value undefined to the interface for HttpClient, because it is type any

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by declaring the Array interface in the global scope

typings.d.ts

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

declare global {
   interface Array<T> {
      http: HttpClient;
   }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation